# New-ADGroup Parameter for "OtherAttributes" ADGroup Email Address?

Tags: active-directory, powershell

**Context**: I'm trying to create an Active Directory Group with an Email address using PowerShell.

**Question**: What is the corresponding attribute name for the "Email" field? I've searched around the web and it seems like an unpopular requirement. :)

Here's how I execute the command:

```
New-ADGroup -SamAccountName $groupAlias `
    -Name $groupName `
    -GroupScope Global `
    -GroupCategory Security `
    -OtherAttributes @{'Email'=$groupEmail} `
    -Path "OU=Distribution List,OU=Groups,DC=SAMPLE,DC=COM"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257203

It's the `mail` attribute.

Comment: Link it now dead. Classic example of why one should copy and paste relevant sections of link into answers for prosperity for the whole lifetime of the Q&A's existance (No web.archive.org, webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache: , or http://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q= versions either)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for this information in the future.

Here's an updated link to the Active Directory Schema for the Group class: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/c-group

Here's a specific link to the mail attribute:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-mail

From the mail attribute:

- **CN:** E-mail-Addresses
- **Ldap-Display-Name:** mail
- **Attribute-Id:** 0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.3
- **System-Id-Guid:** bf967961-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2
- **Syntax:** String(Unicode)